# How can I merge back a string I split?

Tags: c#, string

I like how I can do `string [] stringArray = sz.split('.');`

but is there a way to merge them back together? `(stringArray.Merge(".");)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

String.Join

Answer (score 24):

```
string mergedString = String.Join(" ", stringArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String.Join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is a phone number like:

```
string str = "^^^^^546^64767";
string resultString = String.Join("-", str.Split(new string[] { "^" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

So you can join like this.

Answer (score 0):

string merge = String.Concat(stringArray);